# Setting the maximum number occurrences with `delimitedList` using pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

[pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) provides a helper function, [delimitedList](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html#delimitedList), that matches a *sequence* of one or more *expressions*, separated with a *delimiter*:

```py
delimitedList(expr, delim=',', combine=False)
```

How can this be used to match a sequence of expressions, where each expression may occur **zero or one** times?

For example, to match `"foo", "bar, "baz"` I took a bottom-up approach a created a token for each word:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

dbl_quote = pp.Suppress('"')

foo = dbl_quote + pp.Literal('foo') + dbl_quote
bar = dbl_quote + pp.Literal('bar') + dbl_quote
baz = dbl_quote + pp.Literal('baz') + dbl_quote
```

I want to create an expression that matches:

> **zero or one** occurrences of `"foo"`,
>   **zero or one** occurrences of `"bar"`,
>   **zero or one** occurrences of `"baz"`

... in **any order**. Examples of valid input:

- `"foo", "bar", "baz"`
- `"baz", "bar", "foo",`    // Order is unimportant
- `"bar", "baz"`            // Zero occurrences allowed
- `"baz"`
- // Zero occurrences of all tokens

Examples of invalid input:

- `"notfoo", "notbar", "notbaz"`
- `"foo", "foo", "bar", "baz"`    // Two occurrences of `foo`
- `"foo" "bar", "baz"`   // Missing comma
- `"foo" "bar", "baz",`   // Trailing comma

I gravitated towards [delimitedList](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html#delimitedList) because my input is a comma delimited list, but now I feel this function is working against me rather than for me.

```py
import pyparsing as pp

dbl_quote = pp.Suppress('"')

foo = dbl_quote + pp.Literal('foo') + dbl_quote
bar = dbl_quote + pp.Literal('bar') + dbl_quote
baz = dbl_quote + pp.Literal('baz') + dbl_quote



# This is NOT what I want because it allows tokens
# to occur more than once.
foobarbaz = pp.delimitedList(foo | bar | baz)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    TEST = '"foo", "bar", "baz"'
    results = foobarbaz.parseString(TEST)
    results.pprint()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily, when I see "in any order" as part of a grammar, my first thought is to use `Each`, which you can create with the `&` operator:

```
undelimited_foo_bar_baz = foo & bar & baz
```

This parser would parse `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` in any order. If you wanted them to be optional, then simply wrap them in Optional:

```
undelimited_foo_bar_baz = Optional(foo) & Optional(bar) & Optional(baz)
```

But the intervening commas in your input make this kind of messy, so as a fallback, you can stick with the `delimitedList` (which will strip out the commas) add a condition parse action to get run after the list is parsed, to verify that only one of each of the matched items was present:

```
from collections import Counter
def no_more_than_one_of_any(t):
    return all(freq == 1 for freq in Counter(t.asList()).values())
foobarbaz.addCondition(no_more_than_one_of_any, message="duplicate item found in list")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests = '''\
    "foo"
    "bar"
    "baz"
    "foo", "baz"
    "foo", "bar", "baz"
    "foo", "bar", "baz", "foo"
    '''
    foobarbaz.runTests(tests)
```

Prints:

```
"foo"
['foo']

"bar"
['bar']

"baz"
['baz']

"foo", "baz"
['foo', 'baz']

"foo", "bar", "baz"
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

"foo", "bar", "baz", "foo"
^
FAIL: duplicate item found in list, found '"'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```